# After installing Jupyter Hub and Jupyter Lab on CentOS 7, how do I use them on Windows?

Tags: centos, jupyter, centos7, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

After installing Jupyterhub in CentOS 7 Master account, I want to set up analysis environments and use Jupyter Lab in each account.

I want to connect with Jupyter lab from windows-based computer, so people don't need to log-in to CentOS 7, they just need to write password in Jupyter Lab

**For example**

Linux account : A
Windows web address : https://CentOS 7 Desktop IP:8100
-> Project A venv and folder

Linux account : B
Windows web address : https://CentOS 7 Desktop IP:8200
-> Project B venv and folder

I changed many things and sometimes, https://CentOS 7 Desktop IP:8888 doesn't work.

I set some other port number but it doesn't work.

Now, I'm getting used to set-up CentOS 7 and Graphic Driver, but not the next step. (Jupyter Hub, Jupyter Lab, config.py setting)

**Current Status**

I installed Jupyter Hub in Master account, but I'm not sure I set up correctly in config.py

I changed

1. c = get_config()
2. c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = '0.0.0.0'
3. c.JupyterHub.ip = '0.0.0.0'
4. c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'nativeauthenticator.NativeAutenticator'
5. c.JupyterHub.port = 8000
6. c.JupyterHub.services = []
7. c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'sudospawner.SudoSpawner'
8. c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab'

**Constranit**

1. I've never done it before. I do analysis on Windows, VSCode.
2. Currently, I am working on data analysis, and I want to distribute analysis models within the company so that people who do not know Python can use it to get result.
3. My boss wants to save money, so I'm going to use Cent OS 7 and Jupyter hub instead of using RedHat, Conda and Docker.

Information needed to answer may be missing.

In that case, please tell me what information you need.

Please let me know how to solve the problem or if there is another solution using the free corporate license.